# Using SafeArea in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to understand the [SafeArea](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html) widget in Flutter.

SafeArea code added to Flutter Gallery app [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/13593) in github show   `top:false` and `bottom:false` everywhere. Why do these need to be set false in these cases?
[image]

Comment: As per that discussion, The top and bottom are false now to avoid iPhone X UI fixe.

Comment: Can you add some explanation about which iPhone X UI fixes  they are helping to avoid? I couldn't find anything related to that in the GitHub discussion.

Comment: "https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13594"  => iPhone X: update Flutter Gallery demo to use safe area insets.
Go through the comments and commits.

Comment: please check https://youtu.be/lkF0TQJO0bA

Answer (score 356, accepted):

`SafeArea` is basically a glorified `Padding` widget. If you wrap another widget with `SafeArea`, it adds any necessary padding needed to keep your widget from being blocked by the system status bar, notches, holes, rounded corners, and other "creative" features by manufacturers.

If you are using a Scaffold with an AppBar, the appropriate spacing will be calculated at the top of the screen without needing to wrap the Scaffold in a SafeArea and the status bar background will be affected by the AppBar color (Red in this example).

[image: AppBar with no SafeArea]

If you wrap the Scaffold in a SafeArea, then the status bar area will have a black background rather than be influenced by the AppBar.

[image: AppBar wrapped with SafeArea]

Here is an example without `SafeArea` set:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,  // and bottomLeft
  child: Text('My Widget: ...'),
)
```

[image]

And again with the widget wrapped in a SafeArea widget:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,  // and bottomLeft
  child: SafeArea(
    child: Text('My Widget: ...'),
  ),
)
```

[image]

You can set a minimum padding for edges not affected by notches and such:

```
SafeArea(
  minimum: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
  child: Text('My Widget: ...'),
)
```

[image]

You can also turn off the safe area insets for any side:

```
SafeArea(
  left: false,
  top: false,
  right: false,
  bottom: false,
  child: Text('My Widget: ...'),
)
```

Setting them all to false would be the same as not using SafeArea. The default for all sides is `true`. Most of the time you will not need to use these settings, but I can imagine a situation where you have a widget that fills the whole screen. You want the top to not be blocked by anything, but you don't care about the bottom. In that case, you would just set `bottom: false` but leave the other sides to their default `true` values.

```
SafeArea(
  bottom: false,
  child: myWidgetThatFillsTheScreen,
)
```

## Supplemental code

In case you want to play around more with this, here is *main.dart*:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: BodyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BodyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: SafeArea(
        left: true,
        top: true,
        right: true,
        bottom: true,
        minimum: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Text(
            'My Widget: This is my widget. It has some content that I don\'t want '
            'blocked by certain manufacturers who add notches, holes, and round corners.'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it a good practice to use SafeArea everytime I build a app?

Comment: @MarufHassan I suppose that wouldn't hurt, though if you don't have anything important at the top and bottom it isn't necessary. So it depends on your UI content.

Comment: I think the input from @Paras Sharma is also valid. When you have ConstrainedBox and a SafeArea then you will also need to reduze `mediaQueryData.padding.bottom` from available hight in the ContraintBox.

Comment: Is there a way to get the height of area above the safe area?

Comment: Is there a way to globally do this? The app I am trying to build has a bunch of ListView's and doing this everywhere would be a pain

Answer (score 18):

When you wrap a widget **A** in a safe area, you are asking to the framework "Please, keep my widget **A** away from the device's UI navigation and notches".

The arguments 'top, bottom, right and left' are used to tell to the framework if you want him to avoid the device's intrusions from that sides specifically.

For example: if you put your widget A inside a safe area in the top of the screen and sets the "**top**" argument to **false**, it will be cropped by the iPhone's X and Pixel 3's notches.

Answer (score 5):

SafeArea is a widget that sets its child by enough padding to avoid intrusions by the operating system and improve the user interface.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SafeArea extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _SafeAreaState createState() => _SafeAreaState();
  }

 class _SafeAreaState extends State<SafeArea> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   MediaQueryData mediaQueryData=MediaQuery.of(context);
   double screenWidth = mediaQueryData.size.width;
   var bottomPadding=mediaQueryData.padding.bottom;

return Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: bottomPadding),
  child: Scaffold(
    body: new Container(
    ),
  ),
);  }}
```

Comment: Just posting code without any explanation is not the best thing to do when it comes to understand your answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Without using SafeArea in iPhone 12 pro max**

[image]

**With using SafeArea**
[image]

**Code snippet using SafeArea**

```
SafeArea(
   child: Text('Your Widget'),
)
```

Comment: this is good example

Comment: is there any other way to change statusbar color for some widgets of flutter instead of wrapping in SafeArea?