# Keyboard cancel SafeArea in Modal

Tags: flutter, dart

The safearea in modal is being ignored when keyboard is engaged. It this example you can see modal move by clicking on TextField. How can I have SafeArea in modal and avoid moving the modal when keyboard is activated?

```
Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: FlatButton(
            child: Text('open modal'),
            onPressed: () => showModalBottomSheet(
              isScrollControlled: true,
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => SafeArea( //< when safearea is removed the modal doesn't move
                child: Container(
                  height: 500,
                  child: TextField(
                    onChanged: (v) {},
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `Padding` widget not `SafeArea` in a `BotttomModalSheet` especially because your not dealing with the top of the screen `SafeArea` is little more than just a padding widget in the first place check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49227667/using-safearea-in-flutter) out.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
              isScrollControlled: true,
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                //< when safearea is removed the modal doesn't move
                child: Container(
                  height: 500,
                  child: TextField(
                    onChanged: (v) {},
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

If this is not what you are looking for let me know

Comment: Yeah.. I guess this will be the only option