# Flutter: How to adjust a widget to avoid android's bottom Navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, safearealayoutguide

In my **register** screen, part of the content(at the bottom) is hidden by the phone's bottom navbar. The content is only visible when I close the bottom navbar.

What I want to achieve is, whenever the bottom navbar is displayed on the phone, I want content that is hidden by it to be pushed upwards for visibility and whenever the navbar is removed from sight, I want the content to remain at it's position.

Here is my code.

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Padding(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Register Account",
                  style: headingStyle,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Complete your details or continue \nwith social media.",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.04), // 4%
                SignUpForm(),
                SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.03), // 3%
                Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
                  SocialCard(
                    icon: "assets/icons/google-icon.svg",
                    press: () {},
                  ),
                  SocialCard(
                    icon: "assets/icons/facebook-2.svg",
                    press: () {},
                  ),
                  SocialCard(
                    icon: "assets/icons/twitter.svg",
                    press: () {},
                  )
                ]),
                SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(15)),
                Text(                                <--- HIDDEN FROM VIEW
                  "By continuing you confirm that you agree with our Term and Condition",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Get Screen Size
class SizeConfig {
  static MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static double screenWidth;
  static double screenHeight;
  static double defaultSize;
  static Orientation orientation;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData.orientation;
  }
}

// Get the proportionate height as per screen size
double getProportionateScreenHeight(double inputHeight) {
  double screenHeight = SizeConfig.screenHeight;
  // 812 is the layout height that designer use
  return (inputHeight / 812.0) * screenHeight;
}
```

Visual of the problem
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Any special requirement for using a `SingleChildScrollView`? If not can you please try the code below, if this works for you, here's what it does

1. Replace `SigleChildScrollView` with `Container`
2. Wrap your `SignupForm()` inside an `Expanded()` widget.

Here is the code -

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Padding(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Register Account",
                  style: headingStyle,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Complete your details or continue \nwith social media.",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.04), // 4%
                Expanded(child: SignUpForm()),
                SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.03), // 3%
                Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
                  SocialCard(
                    icon: "assets/icons/google-icon.svg",
                    press: () {},
                  ),
                  SocialCard(
                    icon: "assets/icons/facebook-2.svg",
                    press: () {},
                  ),
                  SocialCard(
                    icon: "assets/icons/twitter.svg",
                    press: () {},
                  )
                ]),
                SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(15)),
                Text(    
                  "By continuing you confirm that you agree with our Term and Condition",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Get Screen Size
class SizeConfig {
  static MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static double screenWidth;
  static double screenHeight;
  static double defaultSize;
  static Orientation orientation;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData.orientation;
  }
}

// Get the proportionate height as per screen size
double getProportionateScreenHeight(double inputHeight) {
  double screenHeight = SizeConfig.screenHeight;
  // 812 is the layout height that designer use
  return (inputHeight / 812.0) * screenHeight;
}
```

Comment: This solves part of the problem, not all. When I use the keyboard there is an overflow of pixels that can only be solved by making the widget scrollable with say ``SingleChildScrollView``. How can you solve that?

Comment: Can you add some more screenshots of overflow issue when using keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Use SafeArea Widget to avoid the bottom navigation bar. To know more about SafeArea widget
click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49227667/using-safearea-in-flutter)

Comment: If you check my code, you'll realize i already have ``SafeArea``

Comment: sry ,I didn't saw that

Answer (score 0):

Add height on your SizedBox like this

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,

        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height. // Add this line

        child: Padding(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Register Account",
                  style: headingStyle,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Complete your details or continue \nwith social media.",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.04), // 4%
                SignUpForm(),
                SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.03), // 3%
                Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
                  SocialCard(
                    icon: "assets/icons/google-icon.svg",
                    press: () {},
                  ),
                  SocialCard(
                    icon: "assets/icons/facebook-2.svg",
                    press: () {},
                  ),
                  SocialCard(
                    icon: "assets/icons/twitter.svg",
                    press: () {},
                  )
                ]),
                SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(15)),
                Text(                                <--- HIDDEN FROM VIEW
                  "By continuing you confirm that you agree with our Term and Condition",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```