# Wrap item different height in vertical PageView - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview, flutter-pageview

I have a vertical `PageView` with different item height :

[image]

But I would like to wrap each item according their height.

The final result I want here:

[image]

How can we do this ?

Comment: share the CODE !!

Comment: Sorry no point to share a simple PageView.builder with color container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UPDATE 2022:

After some time, I returned to this problem and have now created a smart and slim pub.dev [package](https://pub.dev/packages/snappy_list_view) with way more features, less buggy, and maintained code.

```
SnappyListView(
  itemCount: Colors.accents.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Container(
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.accents.elementAt(index),
        child: Text("Index: $index"),
    ),
);
```

For those still interested in a non-packages solution (not recommended), make sure to check out the edit queue of this answer.

Comment: With this solution, an "infinite" or large children list (with image and video) will produce OOM for sure. Would you have any lead to clear / destroy widget according their place ?

Comment: I haven't had a look at it yet, but I wouldn't put all the images/videos in the list itself. I would rather make a list of URLs, and then stream only a certain amount, when scrolling (ex. 10 before and after the element in focus - so the list never gets bigger than 21 widgets). Does that help?

Comment: It help. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you should use `SafeArea` in order to prevent your widgets go through the notch. see [this][1].
Then you should use `ListView` instead of `PageView` because `PageView` creates pages with the same sizes. in `ListView` create an array of `int` that stores height of widget and use it to create widgets with different size.

```
List<int> heights = [100, 120, 10];// and so on

\\then use it as follow:
ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 6,
              itemBuilder: (context, i){
                return Container(
                     height:heights[i],
                     width: 200, // or any value you want
                     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                     alignment: Alignment.center,
                     child: YourWidget);
              },
          ),


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49227667/using-safearea-in-flutter#:~:text=SafeArea%20is%20basically%20a%20glorified,%22creative%22%20features%20by%20manufactures.
```

Comment: Agree. And I think he want the snap effect (auto center the middle item) too. If so, implement snap logic for this list controller should be ok.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes i'm looking for the snap effect, no simple list. Please provide example with the same effect than PageView and I'll accept it

Comment: I think the snap effect only is suitable for horizontal scrolling and cards of the same size. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51607440/horizontally-scrollable-cards-with-snap-effect-in-flutter . By the way, if you want to centerize the items, check the updated answer