# flutter bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar In IPhone it can't full fill, from bottom screen

Tags: android, iphone, flutter

[image]

**in android it is sowing perfect,but iphone it not full fill from bottom.**
**please check bottom:bottomNavigationBar section code........**
**flutter bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar In IPhone it can't full fill, from bottom **
**my code is**

```
  import 'package:country_pickers/country.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:country_pickers/country_pickers.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';

import '../../../authentication/presentation/views/otp_login_verifecation.dart';

class homeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const homeScreen({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<homeScreen> createState() => _MyhomeScreen();
}

class _MyhomeScreen extends State<homeScreen> {
  Country _selectedFilteredDialogCountry =
      CountryPickerUtils.getCountryByPhoneCode('91');
  TextEditingController _phone = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenUtil.init(context, designSize: const Size(360, 800));
    var platform = Theme.of(context).platform;
    final screenW = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: ScreenUtil().setHeight(35),
                      left: ScreenUtil().setWidth(12),
                    ),
                    width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(46),
                    height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(46),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/profile/profile.png"),
                        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)),
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Colors.greenAccent,
                        width: 2.0.w,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: ScreenUtil().setHeight(30),
                      left: ScreenUtil().setWidth(12),
                    ),
                    width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(81),
                    height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(45),
                    child: RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                        text: 'Vishal\n',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 24.sp,
                            color: Color(0xff480377),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            fontFamily: "roboto"),
                        children: <TextSpan>[
                          TextSpan(
                            text: 'Global Rank: ',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xff480377).withOpacity(0.30.sp),
                              fontSize: 12,
                              fontFamily: "roboto",
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextSpan(
                              text: '21',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                                  fontSize: 12.sp)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: ScreenUtil().setHeight(45),
                      left: ScreenUtil().setWidth(145),
                    ),
                    width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(30),
                    height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(30),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/home/menu-vector.png"),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),

        ],
      ),
      //bottom:bottomNavigationBar ---------------------------------------------------
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          child: Container(
            // margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:ScreenUtil().setHeight(60),),
            height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(51),
            // width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(365),
            color: Color(0xFFEFEFEF),
            child: Row(
                // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:ScreenUtil().setHeight(5),),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              OtpLoginVerifecation(phone: _phone.text, country_code: _selectedFilteredDialogCountry.phoneCode,)));
                    },

                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          ImageIcon(
                            AssetImage("assets/home/fi-sr-home.png"),size: 40.sp,
                            color: Color(0xFF6500DF),
                          ),
                          // Icon(Icons.home),
                          // Text('Home')
                        ],
                      ),

                  ),
                  Container(color: Color(0xFF000000).withOpacity(0.10.sp), width: 1.w,),
                  FlatButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:ScreenUtil().setHeight(5)),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ImageIcon(
                          AssetImage("assets/home/fi-sr-shopping-cart.png"),size: 40.sp,
                          color: Color(0xFF6500DF),
                        ),
                        // Icon(Icons.home),
                        // Text('Home')
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(color: Color(0xFF000000).withOpacity(0.10.sp), width: 1.w,),
                  FlatButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:ScreenUtil().setHeight(5)),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ImageIcon(
                          AssetImage("assets/home/fi-sr-credit-card.png"),size: 40.sp,
                          color: Color(0xFF6500DF),
                        ),
                        // Icon(Icons.home),
                        // Text('Home')
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(color: Color(0xFF000000).withOpacity(0.10.sp), width: 1.w,),
                  FlatButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:ScreenUtil().setHeight(5)),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ImageIcon(
                          AssetImage("assets/home/TBD.png"),size: 40.sp,
                          color: Color(0xFF6500DF),
                        ),
                        // Icon(Icons.home),
                        // Text('Home')
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ]
            ),
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**in android it is sowing perfect,but iphone it not full fill from bottom.**
**please check bottom:bottomNavigationBar section code........**
**flutter bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar In IPhone it can't full fill, from button**

Answer (score 1):

The BottomAppBar has a safe area by default. You may probably use BottomNavigationBar or create your custom widget. Check the code below.. That's what bottomAppBar will return

```
PhysicalShape(
      clipper: clipper,
      elevation: elevation,
      color: effectiveColor,
      clipBehavior: widget.clipBehavior,
      child: Material(
        key: materialKey,
        type: MaterialType.transparency,
        child: widget.child == null
          ? null
          : SafeArea(child: widget.child!),//safe area is here
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact answer for the issue, but setting `backgroundColor` in `Scaffold` to same as in `BottomAppBar` and then setting `elevation` in `BottomAppBar` to zero, gives an impression that `BottomAppBar` extends to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

[image: check this image->now it is full-fill]**I Will Solve It. create custom NavBar method**

```
    import 'package:country_pickers/country.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:country_pickers/country_pickers.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';

import '../../../authentication/presentation/views/otp_login_verifecation.dart';

class homeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const homeScreen({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<homeScreen> createState() => _MyhomeScreen();
}

class _MyhomeScreen extends State<homeScreen> {
  Country _selectedFilteredDialogCountry =
      CountryPickerUtils.getCountryByPhoneCode('91');
  TextEditingController _phone = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenUtil.init(context, designSize: const Size(360, 800));
    var platform = Theme.of(context).platform;
    final screenW = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: ScreenUtil().setHeight(35),
                      left: ScreenUtil().setWidth(12),
                    ),
                    width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(46),
                    height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(46),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/profile/profile.png"),
                        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)),
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Colors.greenAccent,
                        width: 2.0.w,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: ScreenUtil().setHeight(30),
                      left: ScreenUtil().setWidth(12),
                    ),
                    width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(81),
                    height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(45),
                    child: RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                        text: 'Vishal\n',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 24.sp,
                            color: Color(0xff480377),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            fontFamily: "roboto"),
                        children: <TextSpan>[
                          TextSpan(
                            text: 'Global Rank: ',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xff480377).withOpacity(0.30.sp),
                              fontSize: 12,
                              fontFamily: "roboto",
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextSpan(
                              text: '21',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                                  fontSize: 12.sp)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: ScreenUtil().setHeight(45),
                      left: ScreenUtil().setWidth(145),
                    ),
                    width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(30),
                    height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(30),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/home/menu-vector.png"),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      //bottom:bottomNavigationBar ---------------------------------------------------
      bottomNavigationBar: buildMyNavBar(context),
    );
  }

  Container buildMyNavBar(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 60.h,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xFFEFEFEF),
        // borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
        //   topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
        //   topRight: Radius.circular(20),
        // ),
      ),
      child: Row(
          // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: ScreenUtil().setHeight(5),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => OtpLoginVerifecation(
                          phone: _phone.text,
                          country_code:
                              _selectedFilteredDialogCountry.phoneCode,
                        )));
              },
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ImageIcon(
                    AssetImage("assets/home/fi-sr-home.png"),
                    size: 40.sp,
                    color: Color(0xFF6500DF),
                  ),
                  // Icon(Icons.home),
                  // Text('Home')
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Color(0xFF000000).withOpacity(0.10.sp),
              width: 1.w,
            ),
            FlatButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: ScreenUtil().setHeight(5)),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ImageIcon(
                    AssetImage("assets/home/fi-sr-shopping-cart.png"),
                    size: 40.sp,
                    color: Color(0xFF6500DF),
                  ),
                  // Icon(Icons.home),
                  // Text('Home')
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Color(0xFF000000).withOpacity(0.10.sp),
              width: 1.w,
            ),
            FlatButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: ScreenUtil().setHeight(5)),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ImageIcon(
                    AssetImage("assets/home/fi-sr-credit-card.png"),
                    size: 40.sp,
                    color: Color(0xFF6500DF),
                  ),
                  // Icon(Icons.home),
                  // Text('Home')
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Color(0xFF000000).withOpacity(0.10.sp),
              width: 1.w,
            ),
            FlatButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: ScreenUtil().setHeight(5)),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ImageIcon(
                    AssetImage("assets/home/TBD.png"),
                    size: 40.sp,
                    color: Color(0xFF6500DF),
                  ),
                  // Icon(Icons.home),
                  // Text('Home')
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The safeArea is likely causing an issue, and you can disable it. This was the solution for my code. However, you should consider if this solution works for you; it is good practice to use the safeArea. Check this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49227667/using-safearea-in-flutter)